# Migrate JSF application to JavaFX

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, javafx-2, javafx

I'm interested how I can migrate JSF application to JavaFX 2.0 Application? I want to preserve the managed beans where I have integrated the business logic. Can I somehow use the managed beans as backed and use JavaFX for presentation layer?

What are the options?

Comment: Read the [JavaFX in Front of JavaServer Faces: CaptainCasa](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/casa-1919152.html) article an [CaptainCasa](http://www.captaincasa.com) - it seems applicable to your situation.

Answer (score 3):

Options:

1. Use [CaptainCasa](http://www.captaincasa.com), which is a framework for taking JSF pages and rendering them in a JavaFX client.
2. Do as Alexander recommends and rewrite a lot of your app to switch the view, control and navigation management to JavaFX.
3. Host the existing JSF application in a [WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html), incrementally enhancing and migrating parts of it to pure JavaFX on an as required/time permits basis.

I'm not a JSF expert, nor do I know your application, so I can't really recommend what might be the best approach for you.  Definitely option 3 is the easiest.

Read [JavaFX in Front of JavaServer Faces: CaptainCasa](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/casa-1919152.html) for more information on CaptainCasa.

`WebView` is not a full browser engine only an HTML viewer, so if you need a bit more functionality, you could adapt something like [Willow](http://code.google.com/p/willow-browser/) or [WebFX](https://github.com/brunoborges/webfx) to handle some of the page navigation aspects that a browser normally would do.

I assume you want to keep the managed beans running on a server rather than integrate them into your client, in which case you are going to need to develop a communication layer to communicate between the clients and the server.  You could use REST for this as demonstrated in the [Henley data sales sample app](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/samples/index.html), though it may be easier to use something like the [Hessian system outlined in this blog](http://www.zenjava.com/2011/11/03/client-server-with-javafx-2-and-hessian-guice-fxml/).

Answer (score 1):

I've found another option to evaluate the trouble - try to lookup in google the next request:

"JSF site:fxexperience.com"

fxexperience.com - site-blog, which supported by JavaFX developers, and except other posts, they weekly provide link batches on different interesting resources.

For instance, I've found such link : http://www.jsfcentral.com/articles/jsf_and_javafx.html

I expect, if decision exists, it could be found there.